# Remove site name from ASP.NET built in web server URL's

Tags: asp.net

I'm debugging a site that is deployed to the site root on the production server, but in my local copy, under the built-in, debugging web server, the URL's include the 'site name'.  E.g. my local site is 'PVLive', so all URL's are 'localhost:nnnnn/PVLive/mmmm.aspx'.  Certain URL's are hard coded in the site's pages to use paths relative to the root, e.g. I get errors when code tries to redirect to 'localhost:nnnnn/Index.aspx'.

Can I do something to keep the 'PVLive' site name out of the URL's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can change the url that your site is run on in cassini (the built in dev server).

I have written an article about this before which you can read here:

- [An easy way to keep your dev and live server urls in sync](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/easy-way-to-keep-your-dev-and-live.html)

The steps from the article are:

1. In the Solution Explorer window you select your Project node
2. In the Properties window (press F4 if you can't see it) you change the "Virtual path" attribute from /ProjectName to /

But you should read the article if you like screenshots and some background info.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your hard coding?

```
e.g. Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx")
```

will build a path relative to your root.

Comment: Done that, thanks, but I'd prefer to not change each page, to better track changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to test it as the root on the dev machine. In my opinion, the closer you dev environment, mimics the production environment less post roll-out issues you have with broken links.
If you dev machine  is Windows server version that you can host it as root on a different 
port.
If you machine is Windows Xp you can use iisadmin.net to host IIS on different ports similiar to Windows Server.

http://iisadmin.codeplex.com/

Remember this is the non-answer so negative votes would be please avoided